# What does this mean, in htaccess: SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1?

Tags: .htaccess

Please, tell me what does this mean, exactly:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
</IfModule>
```

I'm seeing this in Interspire's htaccess file.

Noob question maybe buy I would appreciate some details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to set an environment variable SEO_SUPPORT to 1.  What that actually does on your site depends on the code that reads the variable.

Comment: Oh, so there's no magic to that...All work is actually done in the PHP backend ?

Comment: Yes, the PHP code will examine that environment variable, and do something, who knows what?

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to catch up with Interspire. Thanks for the info.